# Detect Alphanumeric Values in Column to Flag in R

Tags: r, alphanumeric

I have a column with alphanumeric, numeric, and symbol values. I am interested in the values that are alphanumeric, specifically in the format of an acronym followed by numbers (TMR234029 i.e.). Anything that deviates from that is problematic and want to flag as '1'.

I'll be creating a separate column that will consist of bool vals basically depending on the above mentioned criteria.

Comment: I found a solution thanks to another forum. 

strings <- c(
  "TMR-23490"
  ,"TMR23490"
  ,"23490"
  ,"ABC123"
)

grepl("[A-Z]+[0-9]+", strings)

or 

str_detect(strings, "[A-Z]+[0-9]+")

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grepl` and use the pattern

```
grepl("^([0-9]+[A-Z]+)|([A-Z+][0-9]+)$", strings)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

#### data

```
strings <- c( "TMR-23490" ,"TMR23490" ,"23490" ,"ABC123" )
```

Comment: I tried this already and it does not give me what I want. There is a post of how this would work here, and it'll give me true even if there is no letters in the value.

Comment: @purple_plop can you please update your post with some example and expected output

Comment: Hey Akrun, this is what I mean. 

strings <- c(
  "TMR-23490"
  ,"TMR23490"
  ,"23490"
  ,"ABC123"
)

str_detect(strings, "[A-Z]+[0-9]+")

This would give me what I need. Your way gives me all TRUE.

Comment: @purple_plop in this, which all you wanted

Comment: If I use your way, from the example I gave you, I would get all TRUE. The correct output would be FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE.

Comment: @purple_plop  so basically you want both and not any symbols